# Android : Facebook : can we get our facebook profile follower list with latest facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, api

Android : Facebook : can we get our facebook profile follower list with latest facebook sdk ?

Is there a way to get list of follower of our profile ?

Is Graph api provides list of users that are following us.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#subscribers)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/subscribers
```

This will show you the total count if you don't have `user_subscriptions` or `friends_subscriptions` permission, if you have those you would get name and ids of the Users who follow a User.

Comment: This endpoint was removed as of version 2.0 of the Graph API. see here : http://prntscr.com/6z33w8

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/subscribers see here